# How to modify width of the button which placed under DataGridSelectAllButton in WPF DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I need to modify  `Width` of `DataGridSelectAllButton` so i change that using code below:

```
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="DataGridControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="false">
            <ScrollViewer.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Button Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}}" 
                                    Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" 
                                    **Width="20"**>
                        </Button>
                        <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                        <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" d:IsLocked="True"/>
                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Column="2" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" d:IsLocked="True"/>
                        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" d:IsLocked="True">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" d:IsLocked="True"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ScrollViewer.Template>
            <ItemsPresenter  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Problem is that when i change the `Width` of the `DataGridSelectAllButton`,i must change width of the `Buttom`,which placed under `DataGridSelectAllButton` on each row too,but i don't know how?Any Idea?

Comment: Try setting the `Margin` instead of `Width`

Comment: What element should i set margin for?

Comment: Looking at your xaml your button is inside a Grid (Grid.Row="0", Grid.Column="0") so its not the button you want to change its the column/row its in, or span it across columns, do you have a picture of desired behaviour? It hard to tell from the question.

Comment: I don't have any problem with changing width of the button inside HeaderTemplate,as you see above,i need to change width of button inside rows!

Comment: Well i think i found it after couple of hours:
`<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}" x:Key="DataGridRowHeaderStyle">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="10"/></Style>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}" x:Key="DataGridRowHeaderStyle"> <Setter Property="Width" Value="20"/></Style>
```